# Freeing focused custom control dynamically causes crash

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

A custom control that I wrote is implicated in a crash when it is destroyed. <strike>It is hard to pin down the exact circumstances and it might be a factor that the control is parented by a 3rd party control.</strike>

**Edit 8 October 2014**
I've now got a much better SSCCE that illustrates the crash using only TMediaPlayer (from the Delphi VCL) on TForm. So I've deleted a lot of what I wrote before. Please see the edit history for that. (It turns out that CM_EXIT in the former call stack was a red-herring.)

Here's the SSCCE:

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.MPlayer;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu: TMainMenu;
    CrashMenuItem: TMenuItem;
    procedure CrashMenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    fControl : TMediaPlayer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses
  Vcl.Dialogs;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.CrashMenuItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Message');
  fControl.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fControl := TMediaPlayer.Create(Form1);
  fControl.Parent := Form1;
end;
end.
```

The call to `ShowMessage` immediately before freeing the control is crucial.

1. After dismissing the dialog, the `TMediaPlayer` control gets a `WM_SETFOCUS`.
2. It's destructor is then called. Inherited `TCustomControl.Destroy` frees the canvas and then inherited `TWinControl.Destroy` calls `TWinControl.RemoveFocus`, so it gets a `WM_KILLFOCUS`.
3. `TMediaPlayer.WMKillFocus` calls `Paint` directly, which tries to use the freed canvas and crashes.

(Previously I had a custom control where `CMFocusChanged` called `Invalidate`. The effect was the same but the call stack was rather more involved.)

My original 3 questions, that NGLN has answered below:

1. Am I doing something wrong merely calling `FreeAndNil(fMyControl)`? Must I unparent it before destroying it? But this doesn't seem necessary with any other controls, so more likely that will just hide the underlying bug.
2. Should my control have something in its destructor to fix this so that `TWinControl` knows not to try to repaint it?
3. Is there perhaps a bug in the 3rd party parent control? Is it the case that my control should certainly not receive a WM_PRINTCLIENT message once it has started to be destroyed? (The 3rd party control seems to make an explicit call to its inherited `TWinControl.Update` when it receives CM_EXIT as a consequence of my control losing focus.)

But the real question remains: Is there anything wrong with the code in my SSCCE, or is there a bug in the Delphi VCL?

(Incidentally, the same problem will occur with any descendent of `TCustomControl`. I used `TMediaPlayer` for convenience.)

Comment: Are you calling FreeAndNil from an EventHandler within the control e.g OnClick?

Comment: @bummi FreeAndNil is called (indirectly) from a TAction event handler. Not an OnClick of the control being destroyed if that's what you meant.

Comment: @IanGoldby From an action handler is pretty much the equivalent as an event directly tied to it.

Comment: A VCL control receives `CM_EXIT` when it itself loses focus, not when a child control loses focus. So the question is, why is `TLMDDockPanel` receiving `CM_EXIT` at all? `DefocusControl()` only has one code path, and that is if the control being defocused is the Form's `ActiveControl`. It calls `TCustomForm.SetWindowFocus()` and `TCustomForm.ActiveChanged()`, neither of which I see in your stack trace.

Comment: You must not free the control. Instead use `Release` and then set the reference to nil. The control will free itself when it is safe to go.

Comment: @SirRufo Not certain I read this right, but Release appears to be a method of TCustomForm, not TWinControl. I'm destroying the custom component, but not the form or the TLMDDockPanel parent of the control.

Comment: @Remy CM_EXIT isn't send to the control in this particular case. Despite of losing focus, it's also being destroyed which seems to overrule. The parent dóes receive a CM_EXIT, because it contained the focussed control, and now it doesn't anymore. (ie. `Form.ActiveControl = nil`).

Comment: @NGLN: the DockPanel was not the focused control to begin with, so it should not be receiving `CM_EXIT`, unless it first gained focus and then lost it.

Comment: @Remy Enter/Exit <> GotFocus/KillFocus. [See the docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.OnExit): _When switching between controls in separate container controls such as the TPanel and the TGroupBox controls, an OnExit event occurs for the control inside the container before the OnExit event of the container._ CM <> WM.

Comment: A much more better post (a good post) after your edit and definitely a bug in the VCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong merely calling `FreeAndNil(fMyControl)`?

No, every control should be able to be freed at any given time, as long as all references to the control are cleared (nilled) and the instance's code isn't run anymore.

> Must I unparent it before destroying it? But this doesn't seem necessary with any other controls, so more likely that will just hide the underlying bug.

No, indeed no need to.

> Should my control have something in its destructor to fix this so that `TWinControl` knows not to try to repaint it?

No, normally there is no need to. The VCL has this all build in already. For testing purposes or as a (temporary) workaround, you could try to override `PaintWindow` with something like `if not (csDestroying in ComponentState) then`.

> Is there perhaps a bug in the 3rd party parent control? Is it the case that my control should certainly not receive a `WM_PRINTCLIENT` message once it has started to be destroyed? (The 3rd party control seems to make an explicit call to its inherited TWinControl.Update when it receives `CM_EXIT` as a consequence of my control losing focus.)

The parent control indeed receives `CM_EXIT`, because it had a focussed control, and now it has not anymore (ie. `Form.ActiveControl = nil`). So that's normal behaviour. As for why the parent sends a `WM_PRINTCLIENT` to the control (how do you know that request comes from the parent? It seems to start at the `Update` call.) I do not know. To rule out the possibility of a buggy parent, retry your case with a different parent.

---

#### Update (due to question edit):

> 3. `TMediaPlayer.WMKillFocus` calls `Paint` directly...

```
procedure TMediaPlayer.WMKillFocus(var Message: TWMKillFocus);
begin
  Paint;
end;
```

That is taboo! That is definitely a bug in the VCL. `Paint` should never be called directly other than by a request for painting via a `WM_PAINT` message. I have [submitted a report on QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=128195).

> (Previously I had a custom control where `CMFocusChanged` called `Invalidate`. The effect was the same but the call stack was rather more involved.)
>
> ...
>
> (Incidentally, the same problem will occur with any descendent of `TCustomControl`. I used `TMediaPlayer` for convenience.)

That is not the case with a test here in D7 and XE2.

Comment: `Update()` triggers a repaint if any portion of the control being updated has been invalidated beforehand.  So maybe the question is, why has the control been invalidated before being freed? And why is the DockPanel updating the control during `CM_EXIT` handling?

Comment: Thanks. I have now verified that the crash *doesn't* occur if the TCustomControl in the SSCCE above uses Invalidate instead of calling Paint directly. Please accept my apologies - in the process of refining the SSCCE I switched to TMediaPlayer before I removed the 3rd party container panel, so unwittingly introduced a new bug that caused the same crash. I now believe the bug in my original case *is* in the 3rd party container panel.